# Joining multiple tables using PHP relating to a member id

Tags: php, sql, join, mysqli

I'm really hoping that you can clear things up for me regarding JOIN using php as I'm really struggling to come to terms with how it works.

Basically I have 2 tables, one for premium members and another for fans of these members.  So I want to get certain information from the "premium" table where a member (`$memberid`) is a fan.

```
Premium = id, name, avatar, town, etc, etc
Fans = fan($memberid), fanee(Premium ID)
```

So I have this code at the moment:

```
<?php
$get_connections_sql = "SELECT id, name, avatar, town FROM premium LEFT JOIN fans ON fans.fanee=premium.id WHERE fans.fan=$memberid LIMIT 18";
$get_connections_res = mysqli_query($con, $get_connections_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    while ($connections = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_connections_res)){
        $connectionid = $connections['id'];
        $connectionname = $connections['name'];
        $connectiontown = $connections['town'];
        $connectionavatar = $connections['avatar'];

    $connections .= "

        <div class=\"connectionHolder\"><img class=\"connection\" src=\"uploads/avatars/pro/$connectionavatar\" /></div>

    ";
    }
}else{

    $connections = "

        <div class=\"noContent\">There are no connections to be shown</div>

    ";

}
?>
```

This is returning the else condition so there must be something wrong with my JOIN row - Can anyone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Check the value of `$get_connections_res` before the if... if it's falsey then there's an error in the query.  Use `mysqli_error` to report the error.

Comment: Ah right, now it's saying "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: `SELECT premium.id` ...

Comment: Thanks - It's now not returning an error but the problem now it that it isn't showing either the if or else values

Comment: Try adding some random extra output in your if section, it's possible that the query isn't returning any rows, but is still a valid query.

Comment: Yes I've tried that and it seems to be returning only 1 row, where there should be 2

Comment: Then get your exact SQL (perhaps echo `$get_connections_sql`) and paste it in to your MySQL client (phpMyAdmin or other) and see what that returns.

Comment: That returns an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\AppServ\www\music.co.uk\member.php on line 67

Comment: `$get_connections_sql` is a string, you define it on the first line, how can it suddenly become an object?  Are you echoing the correct variable?

Comment: If I take out the WHILE statement it shows the if result that I need but only shows 1 instead of 2 - Could there be something wrong with While?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you are attempting to re-use the `$connections` variable.  Why not just echo the output, or assign it to a new variable (like `$output`).

Comment: You're right - The result is now being displayed correctly - However it's still only showing one output

Comment: Not to worry, I've sorted that now - I had pasted the premiumid into the database and it had added a space to the end so the WHERE statement wasn't matching - Thanks for all your help Phill - Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've said that the column 'id' is ambiguous, this is because you have two tables referenced in your query both with 'id' columns and MySQL does not know which to choose.  You can be specific by adding the table name like this:

```sql
SELECT premium.id, ...
```

---

Additionally, you'll want [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead of `mysqli_affected_rows()`.  Since your query does not affect any rows (like update, delete, insert), instead it's returning a set of rows.

`mysql_num_rows()` takes the result of a query as its parameter (in your case `$get_connections_res`) rather than the connection.  To make sure that the result is valid first check the value of $get_connections_res before the if... if it's falsey then there's an error in the query. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to report the error.

Comment: Thanks Phill for pointing that out - I've changed it but it's still not returning any values?

Comment: Is it getting in to the `if` now rather than the `else` though?

Comment: No, I think it must be an error in the SELECT as it's now returning the error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in ...

Comment: Give it your `$get_connections_res` instead of `$con`.

Comment: There's still no change but looking at it again I think I may have the code backwards - What I have is a table of connected fans and I want to get the premium members information based on that - So if member a is a fan of premium a, I want to return the name, id, avatar and town of premium a based on the connection, if that makes sense - Kind of like having a friends list in facebook and displaying their avatars on your profile